# How do I add a wordpress blog into my existing html website

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a complete HTML based website and want to add my blog to the site.

I want to keep all my design the way it is, including my navigation.

I just want to integrate the blog part.

I guess what I m saying is the blog page to look exactly like the rest of my website without having to change all my website to wordpress.

I have not found anything that will help me except a cut off video on youtube that does nothing for me, and a codex page that does not help either.

Step by step would be great! Any help will be heaven sent. Thanx!

My website where i'd like to install the blog: http://richminded.net/learning-center/index.html

Comment: Please look for a tutorial on the internet. Stackoverflow is not the right place for this question.

Comment: I think you need to develop a blog site with same header and footer as your html site. then in your html site add a menu item and link it to the blog page and in blog menu link them back to your main html site.

Comment: tumblr would be a easier choice for you, if seamless embedding of blogging platform on a specific page is all you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can install WordPress in a folder named "blog" where you current site resides. Then you would just need to install a highly customizable theme and set it to match the fonts, colors, links, header, etc. of your current static site.

Answer (score 1):

You have to develop a wordpress custome theme using your all assets like js files, css files, images and fonts.

and make header and footer as your design and copy paste all the pages inside the admin of wordpress.

To create theme go through the following tutorial

https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

or

http://quandaflow.com/category/website/wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

I had request like this several times, clients wanted blog installed to html site, without changing all site to WordPress. These are possible solutions:

1. **You can install WP on sub-domain like blog.yourwebsitename.com , and
   then add that link to your main website navigation**
2. You can install WP in additional folder like yourwebsitename.com/blog, and then add that link to your main website navigation
3. You can forget about WP and create simple PHP based Blog mechanism inside your web site. Here is a tutorial that could help you https://daveismyname.com/creating-a-blog-from-scratch-with-php-bp

Personally, I prefer 1st option (that's why I put it on first place, see what I did there.. hehehe)... Ok, let's get serious, **if you decide to do this, then you probably want to**:

- Install WordPress on sub-domain ofcourse
- Create a custom template from your original design (HTML to WP)
- Make sure that Analytics are working well across domains and sub-domains

Hope this helps,
All best,

Comment: Why do you prefer 1st option over option 3?

Comment: Simply because I had a chance to work on projects architectured using option 1 and option 3. In my opinion, projects with clearly separated WordPress from the rest of the architecture were always more optimized, easier to scale and generally had fewer issues (then options 3 and 2, for that manner).

Comment: But what about sharing user session on both website and WordPress, wouldn't it get tricky? rather than having the post within the same website? ( with regards to option 1 )

Comment: @simo Sharing session indicates that there are some mutually used features on both WordPress blog and main web site. If these features overlap a bit, than it makes no sense building a WordPress Blog at all.. Instead, this would grown to be full WordPress site (learning management system, customer relationship, directory, forum, etc.).

On the other hand, if these are truly separated systems, there is always an option to configure Single Sign On (SSO), or to build some custom mechanism which simply authenticates against the WordPress.

Comment: @simo Again, all of this is dependent on the project requirements. Initial question was 'How to add WordPress blog in my web site'... not 'How to fully integrate WordPress with my 10+ provisioning services' ... :)

Comment: yea, WordPress option opens the door for sky limits features, thanks for sharing your thoughts